# Different value for Pearson $\chi^2$ in chisq.test() and loglm() from MASS

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I realized that the Pearson's $\chi^2$ statistic obtained by `chisq.test()` is different than the one obtained using `loglm()` from `MASS`. Why is this so? For instance:

```
require(MASS)
k <- matrix(c(15,4,3,10), ncol=2)
loglm(~1+2, k)$pearson
chisq.test(k)$statistic
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the continuity correction (Yates' correction) that `chisq.test` applies by default to 2x2 tables. See `?chisq.test`.

The discreteness of the chi-square statistic makes the continuous asymptotic chi-square approximation relatively inaccurate in some cases; the continuity correction tends to improve the approximation.

For discussion of how this corrected calculation is done, see the explanation in the [Wikipedia article on Yates' correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates's_correction_for_continuity#Correction_for_approximation_error)

If you use the option that stops it applying the correction, you get the same result as `loglm`

```
chisq.test(k,correct=FALSE)$statistic
X-squared 
 9.79063
```

For larger tables, no correction is made in R, and the results are the same with default settings (aside from the warning; NB this data set is in `MASS`):

```
> loglm(~ Type + Origin, xtabs(~ Type + Origin, Cars93))
Call:
loglm(formula = ~Type + Origin, data = xtabs(~Type + Origin, 
    Cars93))

Statistics:
                      X^2 df   P(> X^2)
Likelihood Ratio 18.36179  5 0.00252554
Pearson          14.07985  5 0.01511005
```

vs

```
> chisq.test(xtabs(~Type + Origin, Cars93))

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  xtabs(~Type + Origin, Cars93)
X-squared = 14.08, df = 5, p-value = 0.01511

Warning message:
In chisq.test(xtabs(~Type + Origin, Cars93)) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```